# _pixi2.default.Application is not a constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

When i am trying to integrate PIXIjs with Reactjs I was getting this error

**pixi_loader.js?0eb2:5 Uncaught TypeError: _pixi2.default.Application is not a constructor
    at eval (eval at**

My Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PIXI from 'pixi';
import three from '../../../assets/images/3.png';
import five from '../../../assets/images/5.png';


    export class PixiLoader extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            const app = new PIXI.Application();
            const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics()
                .beginFill(0xFF0000)
                .drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
            const image = app.renderer.plugins.extract.image(graphics);
            document.body.appendChild(image);
                 super(props)
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    {'PIXI'}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default PixiLoader;
```

I have followed this link to work it out.

http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.extract.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Solved it using **require**

> let PIXI = require('pixi.js');`

Answer (score 1):

import * as PIXI from 'pixi';

There is no default export in pixi